# Strange behaviour of isinstance function

Tags: python, python-3.x, isinstance

I have a class named `Factor` in the module `Factor.py` (https://github.com/pgmpy/pgmpy/blob/dev/pgmpy/factors/Factor.py) and also have function named `factor_product` in `Factor.py` as:

```
def factor_product(*args):
    if not all(isinstance(phi, Factor) for phi in args):
            raise TypeError("Input parameters must be factors")
    return functools.reduce(lambda phi1, phi2: _bivar_factor_operation(phi1, phi2,     
                                                            operation='M'), args)
```

Now if I even pass instances of `Factor` to the function, it still throws `TypeError`. A few lines from the debugger with breakpoint set just above the if statement:

```
(Pdb) args
args = (<pgmpy.factors.Factor.Factor object at 0x7fed0faf76a0>, <pgmpy.factors.Factor.Factor object at 0x7fed0faf7da0>)

(Pdb) isinstance(args[0], Factor)
False

(Pdb) type(args[0])
<class 'pgmpy.factors.Factor.Factor'>

(Pdb) Factor
<class 'pgmpy.factors.Factor.Factor'>
```

Any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: wild guess: are you ever calling `reload`?

Comment: @Eevee: Ah.. I was using ipython's `reload` extension. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`reload` is a good way to end up with two copies of the same class from the same module: one from before the reload (if any instances of that class are still lurking about) and one from after.

Most likely you had objects of the new type, but `Factor` referred to the old type, since it was imported some time ago.  So it's completely true that your objects aren't instances of `Factor`...  not *that* `Factor`, anyway.

Never trust `reload`.  :)

Answer (score 0):

As  [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) Return true if the object argument is an instance of the classinfo argument, or of a (direct, indirect or virtual) subclass thereof , it just return true if you pass the instance of your class to it **not the class itself** , see the following example :

```
>>> class A :
...  pass
... 
>>> isinstance(A,A)
False
>>> isinstance(A(),A)
True
>>> z=A()
>>> isinstance(z,A)
True
```

Comment: the pdb session shows that they're objects, not the type